# No data is uploaded, but job status is DONE in bigquery load job using java

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I am trying to upload CSV file, which is in the right format. If I try to upload only 3 rows of data, then it works, but for large file sometimes it says socket-timeout exception our just job DONE. This dataset is in other location.

```
    Bigquery bigquery = GoogleConnector.getBigQuery();
    TableSchema schema = new TableSchema();

    List<TableFieldSchema> tableFieldSchema = 
    getTableFieldSchema("mostRecentObservation");
    schema.setFields(tableFieldSchema);

    Table table = new Table();
    table.setSchema(schema);
    TableReference tableRef = new TableReference();
    tableRef.setDatasetId("MetroMallsEU");

    tableRef.setProjectId(projectId);
    tableRef.setTableId("mostRecentObsTest");
    table.setTableReference(tableRef);

    FileContent content = new FileContent("application/octet-stream", 
    new File(fileNameToLoad));
    Job job = new Job();
    JobConfiguration config = new JobConfiguration();
    JobConfigurationLoad configLoad = new JobConfigurationLoad();

    configLoad.setSchema(schema);
    configLoad.setDestinationTable(tableRef);

    configLoad.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    configLoad.setCreateDisposition("CREATE_IF_NEEDED");
    configLoad.setSourceFormat("CSV");

    //        configLoad.setSkipLeadingRows(1);
    config.setLoad(configLoad);
    job.setConfiguration(config);

try {
        Bigquery.Jobs.Insert insert = bigquery.jobs().insert(projectId, 
        job, content);
        insert.setProjectId(projectId);
        JobReference jobRef = insert.execute().getJobReference();
        String jobId = jobRef.getJobId();
        String status;

        while (!bigquery.jobs().
                get(projectId, jobId).execute().getStatus().getState().equalsIgnoreCase("DONE")) {

            status = bigquery.jobs().
                    get(projectId, jobId).execute().getStatus().getState();

            System.out.println("Status: " + status);
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        }

    }catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check documentation for [`status`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#status) property of job -

`status.state` just tells you of job completed or not
If completed ('DONE') - you still need to check how it is completed  - with or without errors - you can use `status.errorResult` property for this